# Can't import pandas (python) on Mac OS X

Tags: python, macos, import, module, pandas

I'm trying to import pandas by running the setup.py in pandas source package first and importing pandas in IDLE.

After I run the setup.py, I got the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/fanessa1014/pandas-0.12.0/setup.py", line 495, in <module>
    write_version_py()
  File "/Users/fanessa1014/pandas-0.12.0/setup.py", line 228, in write_version_py
    os.path.dirname(__file__), 'pandas', 'version.py')
NameError: global name '__file__' is not defined
```

And this NameError(global name '**file**' is not defined) occurred several times before while I imported other modules. It seems that the issue appears since I'm using OS X 10.9 because everything is fine when I use Windows. Anyway, anyone can help me with it? Thank you so much!!!

Comment: Are you sure about the version matching? The setup.py is being installed for the correct python version?

Comment: Yea, I'm pretty sure. And actually there is no other choice for OS X user, pandas module only has one choice to download for me.

Comment: So, please add the python version & pandas version (0.12.0) to the question. Maybe someone will help accordingly.